# Different redirect with GET parameter

Tags: php, redirect

I´m having this affiliate link (as seen below). Why does this version of the code redirects to my desired target:

```
header("Location: https://www.awin1.com/cread.php?s=2079804&v=10954&q=326996&r=456987");
```

but that version doesn´t lead to my target. Instead it leads to "onepixel.gif"

```
header("Location: ".$_GET["link"]);
```

executed as:

```
linktofile.com/?link=https://www.awin1.com/cread.php?s=2079804&v=10954&q=326996&r=456987
```

How is the awin server able to distinguish the difference?

Comment: perhaps urlencode the link - `header("Location: ".urlencode( $_GET["link"] ) );`

Comment: what is the value of `$GET['link']` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the URL as given (`linktofile.com/?link=https://www.awin1.com/cread.php?s=2079804&v=10954&q=326996&r=456987`), PHP stops to parse the first parameter `$_GET['link']` at the latest at the next best ampersand, so it contains at most `https://www.awin1.com/cread.php`. Follow the advice of RamRaider and encode the URL parameters **before** rendering the link pointing to your page. It should work if the link is given as `linktofile.com/?link=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.awin1.com%2Fcread.php%3Fs%3D2079804%26v%3D10954%26q%3D326996%26r%3D456987`

Comment: Okay that makes sense! thank you! Can you tell me why I get this error now:
The requested URL /http://www.awin1.com/cread.php?s=2079804 was not found on this server.
Somehow the urlencode() adds a "/" to the beginning of my url. Why? It seems to be a link instead of a hyperlink?!